# How to add a variable to action link in html and Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to flask and HTML.

I am creating a user management tool with buttons to do actions (methods) in flask.

I want to add a button where the user can delete a user. The logic to delete a user uses a user_id, which I want to put in my action URL so it can be deleted. I am used to adding variables with

```
`${variable}`
```

but that doesn't seem to work here.

Here is my HTML code. `users` is an array passed in through flask, containing each item listed in the table per user.

```
<body>
    <h1>User Management</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
         {% for u in users %}
        <tr>
            {% for el in u[0:] %}
                <td>{{el}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            <td>
                <form action="/delete_user/`${u[2]}`" method="post">
                    <button type="submit">Delete User</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

Python code:

```
@app.route('/delete_user/<user_id>')
def deleteuser(user_id):
  #logic here to delete user with user_Id
```

How can I insert the variable value of `u[2]` into the action URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a variable using the Jinja templating engine, you can use this syntax: `{{ expression }}`.

So in your case, this is how you would insert `u[2]` into a form action.

```html
<form action="/delete_user/{{ u[2] }}" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Delete User</button>
</form>
```

The syntax you were using before: `${u[2]}`, is JavaScript syntax.

To read more on Jinja templating syntax, check out [this section](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#variables) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

With `jinja` (Flask templating mechanism) you can use `{{ }}` to substitute a template variable. It will resolved before jscript parsing, for example:

```html
{% for u in users %}
 <td>
  <form action="/delete_user/{{u[2]}}`" method="post">
  <button type="submit">Delete User</button>
 </form>
</td>
```

Jinja variables: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#variables